# Rasied errors while trying to access the live wp-admin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I got an error "Missing argument 2 for wp_widget() in /home/content/p/y/r/pyramus/html/blog/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 76". And the admin pages doesn't open

what may the problem of it.Can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deepak saathi,

First you need say, after what this error started to appear? Like: after you installed theme/plugin or after you edited their (theme/plugin) codes.

If you have installed the theme/plugin then you'll have to go hard through phpMyadmin > wp_options table and try to find what theme/plugin you installed.. and just try to modify it (to disable the last installed theme/plugin).

BUT,
If you edited the code then you may want to check this link for reference 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/calling-28-widgets-directly-from-templateplugin

Make sure the codes you've edited have all required arguments AND are called from proper location.

Dhanyawaad

Comment: I have installed the new theme. And it works fine in mine localhost but i it shows the above type error in the LIVE URL.....want to check.....http://theurbanpainter.com/blog/wp-admin/

Comment: sorry Deepak for being late.. looks like things are fixed.
I had to be busy @ Pokhara.
;) lol